How to evaluate an expression in Qt debugger?
I am studying a large Qt/C++ project and am trying to find my way around it, based on the source code and with help from the debugger. I am not asking for help with the project, but I am puzzled by the way the debugger behaves in the following case.
There is an if statement which reads:
    if (multiInstancesProvider()->isMainInstance()) {
        splashScreen = new SplashScreen(SplashScreen::Default);
    }

The precise meaning of this does not matter for my question, I think. My question is the following:
When I set a breakpoint on the "if" line and step through, the marker moves to the "splashScreen" line. I assume that means that the condition at this point evaluates to true. But when I enter the condition multiInstancesProvider()->isMainInstance() in the Name column of the Expression view, it gives <no such value> in the Value column.
With some experimenting I found that if I insert a line before the if statement:
bool condition = multiInstancesProvider()->isMainInstance();
and if I enter condition in the Expression view, it gives indeed true in the value column.
Does this mean that the debugger cannot evaluate expressions, only variables? Or is there a special syntax for expressions? Thanks for any help!
